# Have same column, inheritance with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have 3 entities:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = 'type', discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Task {
    ...
}

@DiscriminatorValue("rank")
public class RankTask extends Task {
    String keyword;
}

@DiscriminatorValue("Store")
public class SearchTask extends Task {
    String keyword;
}
```

Now the problem is when I want to get list of keywords, the first join on hibernate has keyword (hibernate create join automatically) and I can not access the second keyword. Is there anyway to access the second keyword with creating alias or something?

```
getSession().createCriteria(Task.class, "t")
    .setProjection(projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property('t.keyword'), 'keyword')
    )
   .list();
```

Comment: if i had these 3 class i would add `keyword` in class `Task`

Comment: Isn't it strange to use both JOINED strategy and a @DiscriminatorColumn? I thought the dscriminator was only for SINGLE_TABLE

Comment: It has more many classes not just 3 and also I'm not sure, but I think DiscriminatorValue is required, because it fills DiscriminatorColumn with right value on Database.